# Replacing empty values with zeros

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I know this question has been asked many times before, but having followed previous solutions I still can't resolve the issue:

I have a SSRS (2008R2) report, that displays data in a matrix. There is a horizontal column group containing values that may or may not exist: when the value doesn't exist, I'd like to replace the empty cell with a `0`. Currently the report renders like:

[image]

and I'd like those empty cells to have `0`'s in them instead.
The cell expression was set to:

```
 =Sum(Fields!number.Value)
```

so I tried

```
 =iif (IsNothing(Sum(Fields!number.Value)),0,Sum(Fields!number.Value))
```

and

```
=iif (IsNothing(Fields!number.Value),0,Sum(Fields!number.Value))
```

and

```
=iif (Sum(Fields!number.Value)>0,Sum(Fields!number.Value),0)
```

... but the "empty" cells persist. I'm sure I'm doing something daft... but what?

**EDIT:** To illustrate my situation better, my query produces output (in SSMS) similar to:

```
File | outcomeID     | number
A    |    Outcome1   |   2
A    |    Outcome2   |   1
B    |    Outcome2   |   2
C    |    Outcome1   |   1
D    |    Outcome3   |   2
```

... which would produce the outcome in SSRS of:

```
File | Outcome1 | Outcome2  | Outcome3
 A   |    2     |     1     |
 B   |    2     |           |
 C   |    1     |           |
 D   |          |           |    2
```

using a Column Group:

[image]
[image]

Even if I change the expression to be simply:

`=999`

I end up with

```
File | Outcome1 | Outcome2  | Outcome3
 A   |    999   |     999   |
 B   |    999   |           |
 C   |    999   |           |
 D   |          |           |    999
```

... i.e. lots of blank spaces.

**EDIT2:** I've uploaded a very small example `.rdl` file [REMOVED], using the example data above - it reproduces the issue

Comment: Can you handle it in your query?

Comment: @TabAlleman: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: `=iif (IsNothing(Sum(Fields!number.Value)),0,Sum(Fields!number.Value))` works fine for me in a simple test. Can you please add more details of how we can replicate the error, e.g. sample data, specific information on data types, etc.

Comment: Added hopefully useful details above!

Comment: good edit.
though unfortunately for me setting the expression to ==999 works for in mine. is your row grouped on a field or an expression?

Comment: Hmm, even using your example data, `=iif (IsNothing(Sum(Fields!number.Value)),0,Sum(Fields!number.Value))` still works for me. Do you have any formatting on those cells that might suppress zero values? What happens when you create a new simple matrix from scratch with your dataset in your report with the minimum functionality to test this?

Comment: I've uploaded a small sample report with the example data above in it, see the DropBox link above.

Comment: ... and I've just discovered, rather embarrassingly, that `=iif(IsNothing)` etc works on that report. Hmmm. Wonder what's different about the live code?

Comment: is the text box set to conditional hidden?

Comment: @pancho018: You are a genius, and I am an idiot. I'd been fiddling around with hiding values previously, and I'd forgotten to disable this.  I'll credit your answer below, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my first thought was a change to the stored procedure but since i had a similar report to test something on quickly i had an idea.

try this instead

```
=0+Sum(Fields!number.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the following (on SSRS 2005, however): `=CInt(Fields!number.Value)`. It's possible to use other conversions, like `CDbl`, as well.

Alternatively, but a tiny bit longer, try `=IIf(Fields!number.Value Is Nothing, 0, Fields!number.Value)`.

Comment: Did you try it without Sum()? Why are you using Sum() anyway?

Comment: Yes, `Sum()` doesn't make any different. `Sum()` is being used in a horizontal column group to group multiple values together.

Comment: Strange... Can't you use your original query as a subquery and do something like: SELECT *, ISNULL(number, 0) AS number FROM (youroriginalquery)?

Comment: The current values are being grouped horizontally and `SUM`med together; due to the way the report is written, grouping them together within the query would involve quite a bit of rejigging. Frustrating that something so simple is proving so difficult!

Comment: Your original manipulations should do the job... You could try creating a new report, based on a simple table containing some NULL values. See if you can make that work. Then take another shot at this one.

Comment: And you don't have to do the grouping in the query. Just make sure it doesn't produce any NULL values. That's why I proposed the subquery.